# Integral matrices up to unimodular matrices

Tags: matrices, number-theory, integer-lattices

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\N}{\Bbb N}
\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}
\newcommand{\A}{\Bbb A}
\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand{\matr}[2]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \\ #2 \end{pmatrix}}
$
Let $M, M' \in M_{2 \times 2}(\Z)$ be two matrices with $|\det(M)| = |\det(M')| \neq 0$.
Assume that
$$\forall \lambda, \mu \in \Bbb Z,     \quad
\exists U_{\lambda, \mu} \in \GL_2(\Z) \qquad   
M' \matr{\lambda}{\mu}  =  U_{\lambda, \mu} M \matr{\lambda}{\mu}
\tag{*}
$$

Is it true that there is a matrix $U \in \GL_2(\Z)$ such that $M' = UM$ ?

---

Thoughts:

The condition $M' v  =  U_{\lambda, \mu} M v$, where $v = \matr{\lambda}{\mu}$, just means that the two vectors
$\matr{x}{y}   := M  v   , \;
 \matr{x'}{y'} := M' v 
\in \Z^2$
have the same gcd of coefficients (that is, $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x',y')$).

The converse obviously holds (if $M' = UM$ then clearly (*) holds).

If we take
$$M = \matr{ 5 & 1 }{ 0 & 5 }, M' = \matr{ 5 & 2 }{ 0 & 5 },$$
the condition (*) above holds for $(\lambda, \mu) = (1,0), (0,1), (1,-1), (1,1),...$ but not for $(1, -5)$. We easily check that indeed $M'$ cannot be written as $UM$.

I checked experimentally that we indeed have $M'=UM$ whenever (*) is satisfied, it worked for thousands of random matrices $M,M'$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. By assumption, there exist two integer matrices $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $M'\left(\operatorname{adj}(M)e_i\right)=U_iM\left(\operatorname{adj}(M)e_i\right)=\det(M)U_ie_i$. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
M'\operatorname{adj}(M)&=\det(M)\pmatrix{U_1e_1&U_2e_2},\\
M'\operatorname{adj}(M)M&=\det(M)\pmatrix{U_1e_1&U_2e_2}M,\\
\det(M)M'&=\det(M)\pmatrix{U_1e_1&U_2e_2}M,\\
M'&=\pmatrix{U_1e_1&U_2e_2}M=:UM.
\end{aligned}
Taking absolute values of determinants on both sides, we get $|\det(M)|=|\det(U)||\det(M)|$. Therefore $\det(U)=\pm1$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am worried that it is wrong: you seem to claim that $U := (U_1 e_1 \;\;  U_2 e_2)$ works, but for the two matrices $M,M'$ above we can take $U_1 = I_2$ and $U_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ -5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we get $$U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ which not even unimodular. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know that $U := M' M^{-1}$ has integral entries? It has determinant 1 and rational entries for sure; not enough to deduce it is an element of $GL_2(Z)$.

Comment: @Alphonse The two columns of $U$ are $U_1e_1$ and $U_2e_2$. Since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are integer matrices, so is $U$.

Comment: But then U doesn't have to be unimodular as my example above shows. It is not true that M' = UM. There is no such U for the M, M' I gave above (while your U_1, U_2 would exist indeed).

Comment: $$M = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 \\ 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}, M' =  \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I meant that there are a counterexample to your proof. If I apply your reasoning to $M, M'$, I define $U := (U_1 e_1 \;\;  U_2 e_2)$, where we can take $U_1 = I_2$ and $U_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ -5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we get $$U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ which not even unimodular. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alphonse Your $U_2$ doesn't work. $\pmatrix{5\\ 25}=\pmatrix{5&2\\ 0&5}\pmatrix{-1\\ 5}=M'\operatorname{adj}(M)e_2\ne\det(M)U_2e_2=25\pmatrix{-3&1\\ -5&2}\pmatrix{0\\ 1}=\pmatrix{25\\ 50}$.